# multer req.file in nodejs/react projects gives undefined

Tags: reactjs, node.js, multer

I am trying to build an image uploaded to my backend using nodejs and multer in react but the req.file always gives me undefined somehow.

Here is the backend code

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const cors = require('cors');
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path')
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
const port = process.env.PORT || 3002;
const SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY_PATH = './filsufid-710f5c83e46e.json';

const imageStorage = multer.diskStorage({
  // Destination to store the image
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, 'uploads')
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  },
});

const upload = multer({
  storage: imageStorage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024, // 25 MB (adjust as needed)
  },
  fileFilter(req, file, cb) {
    if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(png|jpg)$/)) {
      // Upload only png and jpg format
      return cb(new Error('Please upload a valid image file (png or jpg)'));
    }
    cb(null, true);
  },
}); 

app.post('/uploadimage', upload.single('image'), async (req, res) => {
  const imageFile = req.file; // Get the uploaded image file
  console.log(imageFile)
  if (!imageFile) {
    return res.status(400).json({ error: 'No image file provided' });
  }

  const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY_PATH,
    scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'], // Use the appropriate scope for file uploads
  });

  const drive = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth });

  try {
    // Set the metadata for the uploaded file
    const fileMetadata = {
      name: imageFile.originalname, // Use the original filename
      parents: ['10OuJZ4KCVMR3xciLyCn8ex0NUj9XetXX'], // Replace with the ID of the folder where you want to upload the image
    };

    // Create a media object for the image file
    const media = {
      mimeType: imageFile.mimetype,
      body: require('fs').createReadStream(imageFile.path), // Read the file from the temporary location
    };

    // Upload the image to Google Drive
    const response = await drive.files.create({
      resource: fileMetadata,
      media: media,
      fields: 'id', // Retrieve the ID of the uploaded file
    });

    // Remove the temporary file
    require('fs').unlinkSync(imageFile.path);

    res.json({ fileId: response.data.id });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error uploading image to Google Drive:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
  }
});
```

As you can see i tried to console log the imageFile and it would give out undefined and it executes the if(!imageFile) statement which then cancels the request.

Also here is my frontend code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Navbar from '../navbar/Navbar.js'
import Axios from 'axios';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

function CreatePost() {

  const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(null);

  const handleImageUpload = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    if (file) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (e) => {
        setSelectedImage(e.target.result);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  };

  const uploadImageToGoogleDrive = () => {
    try { 
      const formData = new FormData();
      console.log(selectedImage)
      formData.append('image', selectedImage);

      const response = Axios.post(
        'http://localhost:3002/uploadimage',
        formData,
        {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          },
        }
      );

      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error uploading image to Google Drive:', error);
      return null;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
  
        <Navbar/>

        <h1>Create Post</h1>
        <div>Upload Image</div>
        <input
          type="file"
          name = "image"
          onChange={(e) => handleImageUpload(e)}
        />
        {selectedImage && (
          <div>
            <h2>Preview:</h2>
            <img
              src={selectedImage}
              alt="Selected"
              style={{ maxWidth: '100%', maxHeight: '400px' }}
            />
          </div>
        )}

        <button onClick={uploadImageToGoogleDrive}>Upload Image test</button>

    </div>
  )
}

export default CreatePost
```

I've tried several solutions like and implemented everything such as using the correct formData, including multipart/form-data and adding the upload.single('image'), i also installed any other conflicting dependencies such as express-fileupload however it still doesnt work and the image is still undefined. If anyone could help me out i would be grateful thanks.

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags.

Comment: add your package.json file to the question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example